# Restricting length of a form using simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I'm using simple form for a basic login form for my site within the nav area at the top of the page.

Currently, it's spilling the form fields over two rows and no matter how many `display: inline` attributes I apply. It still refuses to go back onto one line.
What im trying to do is restrict the number of characters in the form so that the fields fit onto one line.

Here's my current form code..

```
<%= simple_form_for("user", :url => user_session_path, :html => {:id => "sign_in", :class => 'form-inline' }, :remote => true, :format => :json) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.submit 'Login' %>
    <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path('user') %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way is to simply use the maxlength html attribute for inputs:

```
f.input :name, :input_html => { :maxlength => x }
```

But that will just restrict the number of characters that can be added into a single input. If your problem is with the width of those inputs, just use CSS to specify a custom width per input so the inputs won't overflow into a second line.